# Including conditional syntax in PHP based on PHP version

Tags: php

I am writing a function in PHP, and in this function, I'm trying to set this up so that I can have the script call the function one way if the server is using PHP 5.6, and another way if it is on an older version. However, when I attempt this on a lower version of PHP, it results in a syntax error. I was wondering if there was any way to force PHP to ignore the new syntax entirely rather than throwing an error if it is using an older version so that I can use this script between versions. Here is the code that I am trying to do this with:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0', '>=')) {
    // This function requires PHP 5.6+
    $stmt->bind_param($type, ...$args);
} else {
    // For older versions (slower)
    call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], array_merge(array($type), $args));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate script and then conditionally `include()` it?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax parsing runs on a different level than runtime parsing. PHP will detect the syntax error before the script even gets to run and your `if` be evaluated.

A possible solution would be as Ja͢ck suggests, use two script files and conditionally include one based on the version.